# Magento - Can't view any products in frontend or backend

Tags: php, magento

Yesterday everything was fine in the webshop.
Since today all products in the frontend display a 404 error. When I try to view the product in the backend I get the following error:

Source model "qquoteadv/source_conditions" not found for attribute "quotemode_conditions"

```
Trace:
#0 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "q...')
#1 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Attributes.php(70): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Array)
#3 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#9 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#10 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#11 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#12 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#13 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#14 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(Array, true, true)
#15 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(250): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout(Array)
#16 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->editAction()
#17 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#18 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/users/ftp/site.com/shop/index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Has anyone had a similiar error or know how to fix it?
Help would be appreciated as the website is live and needs to be fixed ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. clear all caches;
2. check module qquoteadv

Seems like you used to module qquoteadv after that you remove this module, but products have attribute with source model from qquoteadv module.

If module qquoteadv was removed and you are not planning install this module - try to remove this attribute;
**dont forget backup database!**

Comment: I assume I have to remove attributes from the eav_attribute table. How do I know which attributes to remove?

Comment: By source model. Should be something like this: qquoteadv/source_conditions. And you should delete attributes from BO, not direct sql.